# Project not showing up in Cruise Control Dashboard

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol, ccnet-config

I'm new to continuous integration and Cruise Control. But I looked at few examples and I tried setting up a project to a pre-existing Cruise Control setup which had couple of projects in it.

I'm sure, all the files are pointed correctly and I modified the right ccnet.config.

But, the projects I added are not showing up in the web dashboard.

Here is the project block I added in the ***ccnet.config***. (Removed the values in the elements for security reasons, but I'm sure the values are all good.)

```xml
<project>
<name></name>
<workingDirectory></workingDirectory>
<artifactDirectory></artifactDirectory>
<webURL></webURL>
<modificationDelaySeconds></modificationDelaySeconds>

<triggers>
    <intervalTrigger seconds="1200" buildCondition="IfModificationExists" />
</triggers>

<sourcecontrol type="svn">
    <executable></executable>
    <workingDirectory></workingDirectory>
    <autoGenSource>true</autoGenSource>
    <trunkUrl></trunkUrl>
    <username></username>
    <password></password>       
</sourcecontrol>
<tasks>
    <nant>
        <executable></executable>
        <baseDirectory></baseDirectory>
        <buildFile></buildFile>
        <targetList>
            <target></target>
        </targetList>
        <buildTimeoutSeconds>600</buildTimeoutSeconds>          
    </nant>
</tasks>

<publishers>
    <xmllogger logDir="" />
    <artifactcleanup cleanUpMethod="KeepLastBuilds" cleanUpValue="10" />
</publishers>
</project>
```

Am I missing something? Do I have to do anything else after modifying the ccnet.config? Any guidance from here would be really helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Add a project name in `project` tag
- **Check** the configuration file with the application `CCValidator.exe` in `{CCNET_path}\server`
- If nothing appears, restart your ccnet service/batch

Comment: Awesome! CCValidator helped! There was an error. Thank a lot @TridenT

Comment: It's a good practice to validate the config each time you modified it.

Comment: What happened to me was that any change I made was ignored by ccnet. I ran CCValidator and the validation passed but showed what looked like a warning (there was a project with both a `name` attribute and a `name` tag), but ccnet only worked again after I solved that.

Answer (score 1):

Summary of my issue:

There was an error when I ran CCValidator.

There error was with the

```
 <artifactcleanup cleanUpMethod="KeepLastXBuilds" cleanUpValue="10" />
```

which said, Cannot convert String to ThoughtWorks CCnet datatype.

Removed that element and it worked!

**EDIT:** Mispelled *KeepLastXBuilds* as *KeepLastBuilds*.

Thanks for pointing it out TridenT

Answer (score 1):

@Aswin R :  About the issue with `artifactcleanup` tag, you mispell the cleanUpMethod type : `KeepLastXBuilds` (forgot the X in the name).

Reference : http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Artifact_Cleanup_Publisher

Answer (score 0):

Can you add like this in the `<project>` tag

```
<project name="ProjectName">
```